# How can I call parent class differnet operator

Tags: c++, class, overloading, operator-keyword

```
class foo{
   protected:
     int *data;
   public:
     int& operator[](int i);
     int operator[](int i)const;
};

class goo : public foo{

    int& operator[](int i)
    {
       foo::operator[](i);
    }

    int operator[](int i) const
    {
       foo::operator[](i);
    }

};
```

I would like to call parent's class operator.

```
int& operator[](int i)
```

and

```
int operator[](int i)
```

but only one parent's operator `int& operator[](int i)` is called.
how should I fix it??

Comment: Make `int operator[](int i)` in `goo` const too.

Comment: Does that even compile? You cannot overload just on the return type.

Comment: @songyuanyao i updated his code.

Comment: `const` is missing in `goo`, so you have actually 2 same signatures.

Comment: and `return` is also missing.

Comment: and `;` in `int* data` line and after classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really skip const at second operator in goo class:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class foo{
   public:
     int& operator[](int i){ std::cout << "foo[] const" << std::endl; };
     int operator[](int i)const { std::cout << "foo[]" << std::endl; };
};

struct goo : public foo{

    int& operator[](int i)
    {
       foo::operator[](i);
    }

    int operator[](int i) const
    {
       foo::operator[](i);
    }

};

int main()
{
   goo g;
   g[1];
   const goo cg;
   cg[1];

   return 0;
}
```

> ```
> sh-4.2$ main                                                                                                                                                  
> foo[] const                                                                                                                                                   
> foo[]
> ```

Comment: `const_cast`? Why? You only need `static_cast` here.

Comment: There was error in original post both operators in derived class was non const.